# Check unread count of Gmail messages with Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, imap

How can I check the number of unread Gmail message in my inbox with a short Ruby script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ruby-gmail](http://dcparker.github.com/ruby-gmail/)

`gem install ruby-gmail mime`

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'gmail'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> gmail = Gmail.new("email@gmail.com", "password")
=> #<Gmail:0x1ea65d8 (email@gmail.com) disconnected>
irb(main):004:0> gmail.inbox.count(:unread)
=> 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Nash's solution worked for me once I added `require 'rubygems'` as the first step.

Before I did that I would get the following error when using `require 'gmail'`.

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- gmail
```